# Region growing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to use the following source code,

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19084-region-growing

**Driver program**

```
reg_maxdist = 0.2;
I = gray_imread('my_image.png');
imshow(I);
[x, y] = getpts;
J = regiongrowing(I,x,y,reg_maxdist);
imshow(J);
```

I am facing the following troubles,

1. To obtain a point, I first need to click, then press ENTER. (I don't like this. I think pressing ENTER is redundant)
2. `regiongrowing` is not giving any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can use `ginput(n)` to get n points from the user (in your case `n = 1`) instead of `getpts`. Note that `ginput` gives floating points numbers while `getpts` gives integers.
2. `regiongrowing` has a bug - the input should be `(I,y,x,reg_maxdist)` rather than `(I,x,y,reg_maxdist)`.

   ```
   % read image
   reg_maxdist = 0.2;
   I = im2double(imread('lena.jpg'));
   subplot(121);
   imshow(I);
   % let the user pick one point
   [x,y] = ginput(1);
   % round to integer to match required input by regiongrowing function
   x = round(x);
   y = round(y);
   % plot point on original image
   hold on;
   plot(x,y,'xg','MarkerSize',20,'LineWidth',2);
   hold off;
   % get region from seed point
   J = regiongrowing(I,y,x,reg_maxdist);
   % plot region
   subplot(122);
   imshow(J);
   ```

   [image]